# python tflearn - ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 250, 250, 3) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I am trying to create a model to recognize faces. But I keep running into this error and none of the other answers to similar questions have solved this particular problem. The code is the following:

```
X = pickle.load(open('dataset.pkl', 'rb')).astype('float32')
Y = pickle.load(open('dataset.pkl', 'rb')).astype('float32')
X_test = pickle.load(open('dataset.pkl', 'rb')).astype('float32')
Y_test = pickle.load(open('dataset.pkl', 'rb')).astype('float32')

# Input is a 250x250 image with 3 color channels (red, green and blue)       

network = input_data(shape=[None, 250, 250, 3],
                 data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                 data_augmentation=img_aug)

# Step 1: Convolution
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu')

# Step 2: Max pooling
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)

# Step 3: Convolution again
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')

# Step 4: Convolution yet again
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu')

# Step 5: Max pooling again
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)

# Step 6: Fully-connected 512 node neural network
network = fully_connected(network, 512, activation='relu')

# Step 7: Dropout - throw away some data randomly during training to prevent over-fitting
network = dropout(network, 0.5)

# Step 8: Fully-connected neural network with two outputs to make the final prediction
network = fully_connected(network, 2, activation='softmax')

# Tell tflearn how we want to train the network
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                 loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                 learning_rate=0.001)

# Wrap the network in a model object
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0, checkpoint_path='faceRecog.tfl.ckpt')

# Train it! We'll do 100 training passes and monitor it as it goes.
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=10, shuffle=True, validation_set=(X_test, Y_test),
      show_metric=True, batch_size=10,
      snapshot_epoch=True,
      run_id='faceRecog')
```

I keep getting

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 250, 250, 3) for Tensor 'TargetsData/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'.

I have tried everything at this point, and can't exactly understand how to go about solving the problem.

Comment: This is way too much code.  No one wants to download datasets, construct, and train an entire network to debug a `ValueError`.  See how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is of shape `(?, 250, 250, 3)` (based on the comment at the beginning and on the fact that you use Convolution layers early on), your output is of shape `(?, 2)` (based on the fast that your last layer is a fully connected layer with 2 output neurons). Yet, you feed the same dataset to both:

```
X = pickle.load(open('dataset.pkl', 'rb')).astype('float32')
Y = pickle.load(open('dataset.pkl', 'rb')).astype('float32')
```

^^ Note that you load the same file for both `X` and `Y`.

Since I don't know what you try to achieve, there are two possible solutions:

1. If you are trying to build an auto encoder of some sort (in which case feeding the same data set to both input and output would make sense), you need to change the architecture of your network, the convolution layers should feed into deconvolution layers. How to do it is beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer
2. If you are trying to build some sort of a classifier, then you are not reading the right file for `Y`. `Y` should contain the labels you are trying to predict, not the images.

Comment: I am trying to build a model that will recognize faces in images. 'dataset.pkl' contains images of faces. There are a few images that are not of faces. What exactly should I feed Y in this case?

Comment: It should be a matrix of shape `(number_of_faces, 2)`, where for each face the row contains `(1, 0)` and for each image that is not face `(0, 1)`

Comment: Thanks, it's working without any errors. But my accuracy is becoming greater than 1 in the very first epoch and loss is around 4000. My dataset only has 550 images because of hardware restrictions. Any suggestions as to what's causing this and why?

Comment: Accuracy greater than 1 must be some bug in the code. Generally it is a good idea to ask new question on stack overflow for follow up questions, so that more people can see it, and to keep things organized. Also, if this answer answers the original question, consider accepting it.